# cmd - export 1 file name to txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I'm new to scripting so this might be an easy one.

How may I export the name of ONE file in a directory to a text file ? I'm aware **dir > text_file.txt** will output the list of all files in the directory, however I need this to create a loop which will print every file name individually.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which name would you like sent to the text file? The first one? The last one? The 26th one? Should each name get its own text file?

Comment: @SomethingDark I need every file to be written individually. The end result will be the file name and a corresponding value from within the text file. So it will be <file_name>   <Value>

Comment: And how is `dir > file.txt` not what you want? Your question doesn't differentiate between its output and your desired output. Please edit your question to include what you are actually looking for.

Comment: what's wrong with `dir /b >text_file.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly vague answer for a slightly vague question.

```
for /r %%G in (*) do echo %%G
```

to get just, lets say `.txt` files, use:

```
for /r %%G in (*.txt) do echo %%G
```

nicer format if you wish to add more commands:

```
for /r %%G in (*) do (
    echo Full path : %%G
    echo Name/Ext  : %%~nxG
)
```

---

EDIT:

Heres a way to do what you mentioned in the comment, echo all files in current directory to a text file:

```
rem first delete existing output files to clear them.
del full_path.txt >nul
del name_and_ext.txt >nul

for /r %%G in (*) do (
    echo %%G >> full_path.txt
    echo %%~nxG >> name_and_ext.txt
)
```

Edit this however you please.

Do note;

```
rem this will override all content in file.txt with !variable!
echo !variable! > file.txt

rem this will add the content of !variable! to new lines accordingly
echo !variable! >> file.txt
```

Comment: NB: If the file names are written to a file, it needs to have a name that will not match the wildcard path specified (`*` in this case) or it needs to be in a different directory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply however this does not allow me to output all file names in another text file. It only outputs the last result to file name. Is it possible to output all file names to a text file ?

Comment: @joebegborg07 what do you mean? None of that code outputs to a file.

Comment: Ohh..you're using the wrong redirection mark. I'll update my answer to support this knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Arescet it worked for me. I'm trying to combine the echo in the do command with another instruction, so I'm trying to apply to conditions in the do command however I'm failing. How may I combine to commands in the DO ?